# Callgrind / kcachegrind why does running a program in valgrind increase sysCall time?

Tags: profiling, valgrind, callgrind, kcachegrind

I've been profiling some code which likely spends a lot of it's execution time in system calls. Timing some functions manually and with callgrind, callgrind reports system call times of around 20, 30 or 40 times longer than simply timing the function (which would ofcourse include CPU time as well).

--collect-systime=ON was used to collect this sysCall time for each function.

As far as I know, callgrind works by counting the CPU instructions and for timing system calls simply lets the OS do the work and doesn't interfere. I don't understand why the time spent in sysCalls increases when profiling with callgrind, can anyone elaborate?

Is callgrind still a useful tool to profile time spent in sysCalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `--collect-systime=usec` and `--collect-systime=nsec` to see if they are significantly different? `usec` might be a bit faster.

When --collect-systime is specified, Valgrind will be calling one of the various time syscalls for each of the client application syscalls. I would expect that to add a substantial overhead, particularly if your client application is calling very many "fast" syscalls.

Comment: This explains why the discrepency exists, which is very valuable. The value usec and nsec doesn't work on my valgrind, it only accepts yes or no, probably a versioning issue. However I now expect this overhead to be proportional to the "sysCount" which is very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Note also that on top of the overhead used by callgrind due tothe time syscalls, the valgrind core itself adds significant overhead to all syscalls, as e.g. it has to do some sigprocmask syscalls before and/or after the "real" application syscall.